# Update com o select concatenado entre duas colunas da mesma tabela mysql

Tags: mysql

Eu estou tentando executar uma query em que eu vou concatenar duas colunas do mysql *nome* e *sobrenome*, e realizar o update desta concatenação na variável nome completo em todos os registros da tabela.

Segue o código:

```
UPDATE eskalera.curriculum
SET 
nomecompleto = (

SELECT CONCAT(nome, ' ', sobrenome) 

from eskalera.curriculum
)
```

Comment: Está faltando um WHERE aí, não?

Comment: @IngridFarabulini justamente a minha dúvida porque a query é para todos os registros como seria o correto para resolver o problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A maneira comum é usar o UPDATE:

```
UPDATE eskalera.curriculum SET nomecompleto = CONCAT(nome,' ',sobrenome);
```

Assim essa query será capaz de fazer a alteração em todos os registros da tabela em uma única transação. Mas para isso é necessário estar com a proteção contra atualizações indesejadas em toda a tabela desabilitada:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
```

Então teríamos:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0; 
UPDATE eskalera.curriculum SET nomecompleto = CONCAT(nome,' ',sobrenome);
```

Ao terminar, seria interessante voltar a ativar a proteção:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;
```

Assim a proteção contra atualizações não desejadas de uma só vez em toda a tabela é reativada.

Comment: Obrigado é isto mesmo, agradeço pela resposta deu certo!